# "defined as" versus "as defined as"

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis, research

In clinical research protocols, medical conditions of interest are often explicitly defined to avoid misunderstandings.  A typical patient inclusion criterion might be written as follows:

> Patients with established CAD and central obesity, as defined as an elevated waist-to-hip ratio (WHR), ...

Why "as defined as"? Why not just "defined as"?

If anything, the former syntax is more common than the latter in clinical research papers and protocols, but why?  What is the justification for using the first "as"? Is it an error?

Comment: More than a comment, less than an answer: **Defined as** means that is **the** definition. **As defined as** means we are using the following definition *here*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider first a different, and probably unproblematic, use of *as* with *defined*:

> . . . central obesity, **as defined** in Chapter Three . . . .

This is a compact version of something like

> . . . central obesity, **using that term in accordance with the definition** provided in Chapter Three . . . .

Now consider the use of *as* in an alternative version of the OP's example

> . . . central obesity, **defined as** an elevated waist-to-hip ratio . . . .

This means something like

> . . . central obesity, **that is,** an elevated waist-to-hip ratio . . . .

Now, the wording that appears in OP's example is a combination of these two uses of *as*; it means something like:

> . . . central obesity, using that term in accordance with the definition that says that it is an elevated waist-to-hip ratio . . . .

In this reformulation *using that term in accordance with* corresponds to the first *as*, while *that says that it is* corresponds to the second *as*. It can thus be seen that, as has already been observed by Mr. Baskin in a comment, the two occurrences of *as* have different functions. I suspect that, if people who write in this way were challenged about it, they would point to that difference to justify the practice.

A critic of the practice, such as the OP, could, however, argue that, even though there is a difference, the second *as* makes the first one redundant. If we say that central obesity is the same thing as elevated waist-to-hip ratio, then obviously that is how we are using the term in this context. Why else would we give this definition at this point?

A redundancy, as has been pointed out a number of times elsewhere on this site, is not in itself an error. Whether a particular redundancy is desirable or undesirable as **a matter of style** is something on which people may disagree. This use of *as* may rattle some people, such as the OP and myself, but I imagine that some people (particularly those who often see it in the literature in their field) may find it unremarkable.